# Apache Mod_Rewrite Seems to be Causing Javascript Reloads

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up URL rewrite rules for an application I'm developing so that I can use nice clean URLs. I want the URLs to look like `http://app.com/page/agency/` and to be equivalent to `http://app.com/index.php?p=page&agency=agency`. The agency selector is optional, so I want the URLs to redirect, even if the agency is not present. I have created the following mod_rewrite rules for this purpose:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/$ /index.php?p=$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /index.php?p=$1&agency=$2 [PT]
```

This is working fine for redirecting the pages. However, it seems to me that my javascript files are being re-loaded with each page, as if the browser thinks that it's in a different directory and needs to re-load the JS files. The JS files are linked using a hard-coded URL, such as `http://app.com/scripts/dostuff.js`.

Is it possible that the browser is reloading the javascript files each time? If so, have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip rewrite rules below it is a valid file or a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# write single path
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

# write 2 paths
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&agency=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Excellent. I see from the Apache documentation some of what these do... but do you mind explaining exactly what's going on with the rewrite conditions?

Comment: Great! Thank you! The conditions were the missing piece.